# Automated Scan, Save & Attach to Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, automation, scanner, attachments

How do I automate *HP Scan* to automatically save the file and attach it to a new email in Outlook without having to manually set a file name and save? This is *not* the same as the [scan-and-attach utility](http://www.scan-attach.com/) that you click a button in Outlook directly as that would not let them make the scanning adjustments that they're able to using the HP scanning utility.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Questions looking to identify a program are really not a good fit for Superuser.

Comment: It looks like you have provided an answer to your own question.  You should still edit your question, so other people with similar questions, can find your question and understand what it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. HP Scan *will remember which profile you've chosen*, choose "Email as JPEG".
2. Click "Advanced Settings..." near the bottom-right area.
3. Uncheck "Show Save As dialog box".
4. For "After Scan" set "Email the file(s)".
5. Click "Ok".
6. Now the regular steps after everything has been setup are simple. Click scan.
7. After the scan is complete click "Save" and instead of the save-as dialog it will automatically open Outlook, Thunderbird, etc and attach the file.

[image: HP Scan Email as JPEG]

[image: HP Scan Email as JPEG Advanced Settings]